# How to disable crash report on my app on iOS

Tags: ios

I am not using any SDK Crash Report, but after I upload my app to store, it shows alert to clients app crashed, do you want to send log to developer of this app?

Does anyone know how to disable the crash reporting?

Comment: Don't you get crash reports via iTunes Connect?

Comment: why would you want to disable crash reporting in first place?

Comment: Hi @Reinier Melian, I need to disable it ....

Comment: iOS itself won't show alert about crashes. You should find out what shows the alert first.

Comment: as @Mint says you need to find why your app is showing alert about crash is not native on iOS

Comment: I found out, it is native one @Mint, when you archive your app on store, it asks Upload your App symbols to receive symbolicated report from apple, so you should disable it...

Comment: @Steven but this doesn't mean it will show alert. The symbols are only used to 'decode' crash details.

Comment: @Mint, when I use my app on testflight, sometimes it shows the alert that ... app crash, do you want to send log to developer?  ...(means app name)

Comment: @Steven  So far as i know, apps installed from App Store won't behave like that.

Comment: @Mint, Dont know, if it is something related to iOS 13 or only in TestFlight, I will try to ask from apple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer my question here maybe it can help someone:

When I install the app from TestFlight and if the app crashes Apple sends an automatic report to the user by showing alert message. But if the app is installed from the App Store, Apple doesn't show the crash report alert to user. The user can check the report from analytics.